# How to format a date in Calc?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, openoffice-calc, date-format

When I enter `09/02/2013 00:00:00` in a cell in Windows 7, the cell displays `02.09.2013 00:00`.

I have specified the proper **Format code** in **Format Cells**:

[image: screenshot]

In Windows XP, the outcome is as expected. The input `09/02/2013 00:00:00` gets displayed as `09.02.2013 00:00`.

How to can fix this?

Comment: here is image from format cells http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifq96.png

Comment: It sounds like your global system date format on the Windows 7 PC is US format (MM/DD/YYYY) rather than European (DD/MM/YYYY) so when you enter the formula, it "looks" OK but is in fact wrong.  If you attempt to enter "21/07/2013", what happens?

Comment: i changed format in Regional and Language Options and looks like its working now :)

Comment: If @PJC doesn't add an answer, you can answer your own question explaining how you solved your problem. To mark your question as *solved* you can accept that answer. We don't add *[Solved]* to the question title here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing (and as per my comment), changing the global system date format (which controls how all applications *accept* dates) from US (MM/DD/YYYY) to EU (DD/MM/YYYY) should be the solution.

As you found, this is set in "Regional and Language Options".